# How to create simple OpenGL window on Mac?

Tags: macos, opengl

OSX version: 10.13 - High Sierra

Macbook Pro Late 2011

Xcode: 9

Level: Beginner

I looked at the OpenGL programming guide in Apple doc, but the documentation was not that friendly, so I did not tried it yet.

I did google research and youtube about how to simply create a window for getting started, I have successfully created a Window with rectangle of my desired color using XCode. But it was OpenGL v2 and there were many deprecation warnings.

I want to develop OpenGL outside of XCode environment but I failed to compile it and here is my main.cpp

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>

void display () {

    glClearColor ( 1.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f );

    glClear ( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    glLoadIdentity ();

    glFlush ();

}

int main ( int argc, char** argv ) {

    glutInit ( &argc, argv );

    glutInitDisplayMode ( GLUT_SINGLE );

    glutInitWindowSize ( 640, 480 );

    glutInitWindowPosition ( 100, 100 );

    glutCreateWindow ( "Baby GL" );

    glutDisplayFunc ( display );

    glutMainLoop ();

    return 0;

}
```

I am using vscode + vim as main text editor

Here is how i compile the main.cpp in the terminal:

`g++ -pipe --std=c++14 main.cpp -lm`

I tried compiling them without code in the main and the libraries include did not thrown any error, after then I copy paste all the code back into main, and compile it, it thrown this error:

```
7 warnings generated. // just deprecation warning
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_glClear", referenced from:
  display() in main-26b0d3.o
"_glClearColor", referenced from:
  display() in main-26b0d3.o
"_glFlush", referenced from:
  display() in main-26b0d3.o
"_glLoadIdentity", referenced from:
  display() in main-26b0d3.o
"_glutCreateWindow", referenced from:
  _main in main-26b0d3.o
"_glutDisplayFunc", referenced from:
  _main in main-26b0d3.o
"_glutInit", referenced from:
  _main in main-26b0d3.o
"_glutInitDisplayMode", referenced from:
  _main in main-26b0d3.o
"_glutInitWindowPosition", referenced from:
  _main in main-26b0d3.o
"_glutInitWindowSize", referenced from:
  _main in main-26b0d3.o
"_glutMainLoop", referenced from:
  _main in main-26b0d3.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those errors mean the linker couldn't find those functions anywhere.

You have to compile/link using `-framework Cocoa` and `-framework OpenGL`. As you're using GLUT, then you also need to download it as a pre-compiled framework and append `-framework GLUT` to the compiling/linking flags.